# Get all date between two date even not existing where query skip existing record in range

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a database table where I need to get all date between two date (even non-existing dates) where the query would skip those records which match to any date in set.

Example:

```
Start date: 2018-03-11 00:00:00
End date: 2019-03-11 00:00:00
Interval: 1 month
```

In database I have two record:

```
2018-03-11 00:00:00 and 2018-04-11 00:00:00
```

The result would be something like:

```
2018-05-11 00:00:00 through 2019-03-11 00:00:00
```

As we see the result omits the first 2018-03-11 00:00:00 and second 2018-04-11 00:00:00 records but prints out the rest.

I would be glad I somebody could give me a little guidance in this.

I was trying to implement something in half PHP half MySQL but localized date formating brought only nightmares. I was using something like this in PHP:

```
public function getDateRange($start, $end, $interval, $type)
{
    if ($type === 'month') {
        $interval = new DateInterval('P' . $interval . 'M');
    } elseif ($type === 'day') {
        $interval = new DateInterval('P' . $interval . 'D');
    } elseif ($type === 'year') {
        $interval = new DateInterval('P' . $interval . 'Y');
    }

    $start = new DateTime($start, $this->serverTimezone);
    $end = new DateTime($end, $this->serverTimezone);
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $result = [];

    foreach ($period as $date) {
        $result[] = $date->format($this->datetimeFormat);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Database table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `es_servicepayment` (
`servicepayment_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`servicepayment_amount` decimal(11,3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`servicepayment_interval` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`servicepayment_type` enum('day','month','year') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`paymenttype_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`servicepayment_added` datetime NOT NULL,
`servicepayment_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
`service_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Table data:

```
INSERT INTO `es_servicepayment` (`servicepayment_id`, `servicepayment_amount`, `servicepayment_interval`, `servicepayment_type`, `paymenttype_id`, `servicepayment_added`, `servicepayment_updated`, `service_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, '23.000', 1, 'month', 1, '2018-03-11 00:00:00', '2018-03-11 00:00:00', 1, 1),
(2, '23.000', 1, 'month', 1, '2018-04-11 00:00:00', '2018-04-11 00:00:00', 1, 1);
```

I would need something like this:

```
2018-05-11 00:00:00
2018-06-11 00:00:00
2018-07-11 00:00:00
2018-08-11 00:00:00
2018-09-11 00:00:00
2018-10-11 00:00:00
2018-11-11 00:00:00
2018-12-11 00:00:00
2019-01-11 00:00:00
2019-02-11 00:00:00
2019-03-11 00:00:00
```

except dates already stored in the database:

```
2018-03-11 00:00:00
2018-04-11 00:00:00
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Never mind. Case already resolved. The way it works is I select already stored dates from database then generate range of dates in PHP afterwards I am doing an array_diff() on both arrays, this way the result contains only dates which are not present in the database.

Comment: You're welcome to accept your own answer, or otherwise delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Case already resolved. The way it works is I select already stored dates from database then generate range of dates in PHP afterwards I am doing an array_diff() on both arrays, this way the result contains only dates which are not present in the database.